# Referencing a table in latex

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, captions

My latex document is given below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\linespread{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color} 
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} 
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[textwidth=16cm,textheight=24cm,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=red]{hyper ref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Large\centering}{Chapter \thechapter:}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\itshape \nouppercase \leftmark}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}  
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5cm} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Parameters}
\begin{tabular}{ p{6cm} p{4cm} p{4cm}  }    
\hline \\ 
\textsc{Demo 1} \\
Characteristics & \textsc{Water} & \textsc{Air}    \\ 
\hline 
Density & 1000 & 1.25 \\
State  &  liquid & Gas \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption*{Table 1}
\label{table1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In the above table I would like to make reference to the table using the "table1" label in the code. However, when I use \ref{table1}, it does not seem to refer me to the table. Also, The first caption on top (`\caption{Parameters}`) does not seem to appear in my table. I would really appreciate any help with these issues. I must be missing something quite obvious.

Thanks

Comment: There some compilation errors... please fix your MWE first. You use two captions for the table. Why `\linespread{}` before `\documentclass`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, sry about that, I've removed the bugs, it should compile now. I've also changed the position of linespread.

Comment: Did you compile multiple times?

Comment: @John, `restylefloat{table}` screws up the positioning, two times `\usepackage{caption}` is useless

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at the [guide for how to minimalize your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225).

Comment: @Sverre, Thanks for your comment. The document I'm working on is a much longer document hence the reason for the remaining unused codes. The reason I included all the other packages is to find out which one could be causing the problem (as has been pointed out below). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @John Yes, it makes sense, but it's still not what you should do. You shouldn't dump your entire preamble on this site and ask us to figure out what is causing the problem. _You_ should do the task of removing code line by line, and eventually you'll figure out what's causing the problem. Then you can ask us why that particular line of code causes the problem you've identified. Please read the top three answers to [how to write a minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @Sverre, thanks for your suggestion. Your point has been noted and I've also read the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\restylefloat` causes the `caption` positioning problem and `\label` after `\caption*{}` is useless!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\linespread{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color} 
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} 
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[textwidth=16cm,textheight=24cm,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=red]{hyper ref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Large\centering}{Chapter \thechapter:}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\itshape \nouppercase \leftmark}
\usepackage{float}
%\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}  
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5cm} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Parameters}
\begin{tabular}{ p{6cm} p{4cm} p{4cm}  }    
\hline \\ 
\textsc{Demo 1} \\
Characteristics & \textsc{Water} & \textsc{Air}    \\ 
\hline 
Density & 1000 & 1.25 \\
State  &  liquid & Gas \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\caption*{Table 1}
\label{table1}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ p{6cm} p{4cm} p{4cm}  }    
\hline \\ 
\textsc{Demo 1} \\
Characteristics & \textsc{Water} & \textsc{Air}    \\ 
\hline 
Density & 1000 & 1.25 \\
State  &  liquid & Gas \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption*{Parameters}
\label{table2} %%% Useless -- done on purpose here!!!
\end{table}
Table \ref{table1} and another Table \ref{table2} has no influence
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No comments please on `\label` after `\caption*{}` -- this is done on purpose to show the problem

Comment: Thanks Christian, it works well now. I'm glad I've learned something new about latex.

Answer (score 2):

Remove these two lines:

```
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
```

You are back in business.

Comment: Damn,you were quicker ;-)